# Why Android Studio Removie "Android drawable importer" from Plugin Section?

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins

In old version of Android Studio i use "android drawable importer" plugin for add Pic in all Drawables folder in One click.

But now i see in this latest version of android studio. Here this Plugin is not available. So why Android Studio remove this plugin. Is any issue with this latest android studio version ?